# If numbers are equal can be I sure that results of any mathematical operation on them are also equal?

Tags: java, floating-point

Suppose I have six *double* numbers: *a, b, c, a2, b2, c2*

I know that:

```
a == a2
b == b2
c == c2
```

Can I be sure that on all platforms and JVM versions:

```
a * b + c == a2 * b2 + c2 // This runs within the same JVM process
```

It is assumed that the result of this operation is finite (not infinity) and not NaN

Comment: Java has a `strictfp` keyword which enforces deterministic floating-point semantic for all platforms. In your case it should be okay, I guess. But I'm not sure whether the JIT can opt to calculate one side in one pass and the other maybe via storing the values somewhere else (maybe if a thread interrupted) which could cause problems. But I have no actual idea there.

Comment: If the result is NaN they won't compare equal. NaN isn't finite, but it's also not infinity..

Comment: The result can not be NaN here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless your class or method is declared with the `strictfp` modifier, you can't be sure that `a * b + c == a2 * b2 + c2` is true.

If you declare your class or method to be `strictfp`, the behaviour of floating point arithmetic is well defined and must be consistent both within the Java VM, as well as across different platforms ([Java Language Specification $15.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.4)).

If the class or method is *not* declared with `strictfp`, the Java VM is allowed to use platform or hardware specific functions for floating point arithmetics to obtain better performance at the cost of predictability. Since the JLS in this case does not even mandate consistency within the same VM, it means that the same VM is allowed to produce different results if the exact same calculation is performed more than once. I would e.g. assume that at least comparing interpreted byte code and JIT-compiled bytecode will or at least may produce different results. So even if it is admittedly very unlikely that the two sides of the expression `a * b + c == a2 * b2 + c2` evaluate to different results, the JLS allows for it.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the Java requirements about floating-point arithmetic apply to the base operations, including those explicitly asked about in the question. However, it one uses other mathematical operations, there is no guarantee. The functions in `java.lang.Math` are allowed to return results slightly different from correctly rounded results and may vary from implementation to implementation.

Comment: As I read the Java specification, it does not seem to grant a great deal of license to floating-point operations without `strictfp`. It allows them to have an extended exponent range but not to have greater precision or different rounding. Do you concur? If so, then the results of floating-point arithmetic must be the same as long as the normal exponent range is not exceeded.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: I am really not sure. The JLS paragraph on FP-strict statements I linked to is written in a rather colloquial style and e.g. talks about "some leeway". It is clear how FP-strict statements are calculated, but IMHO not exactly clear what kind of and how much leeway is allowed for the VM to optimize the statement execution.